# HP Code 341 "Physical Drive State: Predictive failure. This physical drive is predicted to fail soon."

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, raid5, hp-smart-array, failed

this is my first post so bear with me here :-)

**Background:**
I have a RAID5 setup with 4 disks that have been working perfect for years.
After one drive failed, I installed new drives which where rebuilding but
it will mark new drives as smart status fail.

**Hardware:**
HP Proliant ML350 G6, 6Gb RAM, Xeon E5620, BIOS D22
Windows server 2008R2 (updated)
Smart Array P410i
4x 300Gb SAS disks 10k

**Situation:**
I bought 6 new hard drives and during rebuild of the array it gets smart status failed. I have tried 5 out of 6 drives and all get the same error.

**What I have done:**
Updated to latest FW for the raid controller and a couple of the hard drives.

I tried to set up another logical drive with raid1 using two of these new drives to test them and it worked without any problem.

All drives have been inserted and taken out during power-on.

**Thoughts and questions:**
Could really all 5 be broken?

Is there any way to clear the smart-fail status?

Here is a fresh taken report from the ACU:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15772069/report-4bef4a9c-00000cf8-00000000.zip , the important-looking bit of which says:

```
ACU Version                             8.70.9.0
Diagnostic Module Version               5.2.64.0
INFOMGR Version                         6.0.1.0
Time Generated                          Monday November 23, 2015 9:22:40AM

Device Summary:
   Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot

Consolidated Error Report:
   Controller: Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot
       Device: Physical Drive 1I:1:2
      Message: The physical drive has failed.
   Controller: Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot
       Device: Physical Drive 2I:1:6
      Message: Physical Drive State: Predictive failure. This physical drive is predicted to fail soon.
   Controller: Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot
       Device: Physical Drive 2I:1:7
      Message: Physical Drive State: Predictive failure. This physical drive is predicted to fail soon.

Report for Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot
---------------------------------------------

Smart Array P410i in Embedded Slot : Device Error Report

Device                Severity Error                                                                                    
--------------------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Physical Drive 1I:1:2 Critical The physical drive has failed.
Physical Drive 2I:1:6 Warning  Physical Drive State: Predictive failure. This physical drive is predicted to fail soon.
Physical Drive 2I:1:7 Warning  Physical Drive State: Predictive failure. This physical drive is predicted to fail soon.
```

---

I replaced the drives with another batch and now it seems that smart staus is ok but sometimes Windows complains about faulty blocks or so. :S

These 6 new drives with smart status fail is now inside another server. It is a ML350 G6 with Latest firmware on the P410i controller and also the drives(I think). I have put all 6 drives into a new RAID5 drive and just initialized it finished. It seems working very well but still smart status fail.

I did a CTRL ALL SHOW CONFIG DETAIL, and here is the output. Is there any way of reset the smart staus or so?

```
Smart Storage Administrator CLI 2.60.18.0
```

Detecting Controllers...Done.
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

`
=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Serial Number: 5001438005EDDF40
   Cache Serial Number: PACCQ9SY70JU
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: C
   Firmware Version: 6.64-0
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Parallel Surface Scan Supported: No
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: Permanently Disabled
   Cache Status Details: The cache is disabled because one or more attached batteries are not supported by the currently running firmware.
   Cache Ratio: 25% Read / 75% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 256 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 144 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Batteries
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: Failed (Replace Batteries)
   SATA NCQ Supported: True
   Number of Ports: 2 Internal only
   Driver Name: HpSAMD.sys
   Driver Version: 8.0.4.0
   PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:04:00.0
   Host Serial Number: CZJ941003H
   Sanitize Erase Supported: False
   Primary Boot Volume: None
   Secondary Boot Volume: None

Port Name: 1I
         Port ID: 0
         Port Connection Number: 0
         SAS Address: 5001438005EDDF40
         Port Location: Internal

Port Name: 2I
         Port ID: 1
         Port Connection Number: 1
         SAS Address: 5001438005EDDF44
         Port Location: Internal

Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK

```
  Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
  Drive Bays: 4
  Port: 1I
  Box: 1
  Location: Internal
```

Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)

Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 1, OK

```
  Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
  Drive Bays: 4
  Port: 2I
  Box: 1
  Location: Internal
```

Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS HDD, 300 GB, Predictive Failure)

Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB (0.0%)
      Used Space: 1.6 TB (100.0%)
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data

```
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 1.4 TB
     Fault Tolerance: 5
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 64 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 320 KB
     Status: OK
     Caching:  Disabled
     Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
     Unique Identifier: 600508B1001030354544444634300500
     Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive0 (Disk 0) (Bus: 0,Target: 4,Lun: 0)
     Mount Points: Offline 500 MB Partition Number 1, C:\ 146.0 GB Partition Number 2, D:\ 1.2 TB Partition Number 3
     Logical Drive Label: A0017FDF5001438005EDDF40CEA0
     Drive Type: Data
     LD Acceleration Method: All disabled

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 1
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE52A2P0000B213CFP2
     WWID: 5000C500437249DD
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 33
     Maximum Temperature (C): 62
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

  physicaldrive 1I:1:2
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 2
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE51A8S0000B213BAGM
     WWID: 5000C5004371B7C5
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 33
     Maximum Temperature (C): 68
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

  physicaldrive 1I:1:3
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 3
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE519840000B212DHLM
     WWID: 5000C500437278E1
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 31
     Maximum Temperature (C): 63
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

  physicaldrive 2I:1:5
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 5
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE521XZ0000B213B62Z
     WWID: 5000C50043760E91
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 32
     Maximum Temperature (C): 63
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

  physicaldrive 2I:1:6
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 6
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE519140000B213A6SG
     WWID: 5000C5004371FB05
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 33
     Maximum Temperature (C): 67
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

  physicaldrive 2I:1:7
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 7
     Status: Predictive Failure
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPDG
     Serial Number: 6SE5194L0000B213BC7W
     WWID: 5000C50043720255
     Model: HP      EG0300FAWHV
     Current Temperature (C): 31
     Maximum Temperature (C): 60
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None
```

SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250
      Device Number: 250
      Firmware Version: RevC
      WWID: 5001438005EDDF4F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model: SRC 8x6G

=>`

Here is a fresh ADUreport too after init is done:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15772069/ADUReport%20after%20init.zip

Comment: From whom did you buy the new HDDs?  That is, are they proper HP parts, or did you buy six drives that seemed to be about the right thing?

Comment: Please post the output of the `hpssacli` or `hpacucli` tool: `ctrl all show config detail` - You will want to update the firmware of all the drives as well.

Comment: All new drives was hp original parts new in anti static bags.
Unfortunately they had been put together in a large box with too little packing material if you ask me. So they might got broken during shipping.

I will get back soon with detail config as asked.

Just fyi:
Bay 1-4 is the original bays for the raid drives.

Comment: I have made an diagnostic report above and put in on Dropbox, isnt the configuration embedded in that very detailed report?

Comment: I might have ordered the wrong disks, I think they old one are Dual port and new one single port or vice versa. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No, dual-port and single-port are compatible when used _inside_ of a server.

Comment: Please don't add new information as an answer, instead edit your post. And please use the formatting tools to make it easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all 5 new HDs are of the correct type, it's extremely unlikely that all of them are faulty.  We've had a similar problem of an HP ProLiant NAS with new disks constantly failing, and we solved it by replacing the disk controller.

Comment: THe original drives is HP EG0300FBDBR and the new ones is EG0300FAWH. Is that compatible?

Comment: They seem to have the same specs, however it'd be better to ask HP support about this, giving them the model of your ProLiant NAS.

Comment: I am about now to test the final one of six that I ordered. I have also bought 4 other drive from other place which are exactly the same model as original. Will get back with how it goes.